# trouble with JavaScript event listeners

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseevent

I have a div container with three normal divs inside and three absolutely positioned divs that lie below the normal other three, so six divs in total and a little bit of paragraph text. what i am going for is when i hover on each of the three normal divs, the paragraph and the absolutely positioned divs to come on top and when it is not hovered, the normal divs to be on top. i have got it almost working, it is just unreliable.

```js
const allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
const allOverlays = document.getElementsByClassName("overlay");
const details = document.getElementsByClassName("details");

const showOverlays = (e) => {
    let target = e.target.className;
    let index = parseInt(target[3]);
    allOverlays[index].style.zIndex = '2';
    details[index].style.display = 'block';
}

const hideOverlays = (e) => {
    let target = e.target.className;
    let index = parseInt(target[7]);
    allOverlays[index].style.zIndex = '-1';
    details[index].style.display = 'none';
}

for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
    allDivs[i].addEventListener('mouseover', showOverlays)
}

for(let i=0; i < 3; i++){
    allOverlays[i].addEventListener('mouseout', hideOverlays)
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 50vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  background-color: blue;
  gap: 10vw;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.overlay {
  width: 220px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: brown;
  z-index: -1;
}

.overlay1, .det1 {
  left: 26.7vw;
}

.overlay2, .det2 {
  left: 53.5vw;
}

.details {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="overlay0 overlay" ></div>
        <div class="div0 content"></div>
        <div class="det0 details">
            <p>details</p>
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay1 overlay"></div>
        <div class="div1 content"></div> 
        <div class="det1 details">
            <p>details</p>
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
        <div class="overlay2 overlay"></div>
        <div class="div2 content"></div> 
        <div class="det2 details">
            <p>details</p>
            <p>details</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your case the problem is in the **mouseleave** event and the **details** element, I will explain the reason of the weird behavior:

1. this only happens when the cursor goes over the details element
2. when the cursor goes over the **P** element a mouse leave event is triggered and right after a mouse enter/over event is triggered
3. as the **P** element has no margin and is overlapping the **overlay div** so when your cursor leaves the **P** element towards to another div the mouse leave event is **not** triggered, and that's the reason why the overlay stays after leaving the div.
   **So keep in mind that the edges of your overlay div should not be overlapped by any other div if you want the leave event to be triggered**

a workaround for this is add a margin to **details class** and increase the width size of the container class, like so:

```
.container {
  width: 75vw; /* increased to 75 */
  height: 50vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3,1fr);
  background-color: blue;
  gap: 10vw;
  margin: 20vh auto;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.details {
  margin: 15px; /* added margin */
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  display: none;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

but this is not a definitive solution, as the problem should appears again if you change the styles.

what I did on my project was add a condition in the mouse leave event, something like this:

```
const hideElement = (e) => {
  if(e.relatedTarget === "someOuterDiv") {
    // close the element
  }
}
```

in the example above the event is only triggered if the cursor goes towards an outer div, but unfortunately this will not work in your case as you have sibling elements that need to be closed too.